# How to use persistent disk in a Replication Controller ? Google cloud / kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I would like to use persistent disk in my replication controller but if i use a `gcePersistentDisk` the console returns me an error

> ReadOnly must be true for replicated pods > 1, as GCE PD can only be mounted on multiple machines if it is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message and from the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/volumes.html#gcepersistentdisk):

> A feature of PD is that they can be mounted as read-only by multiple consumers simultaneously. This means that you can pre-populate a PD with your dataset and then serve it in parallel from as many pods as you need. Unfortunately, PDs can only be mounted by a single consumer in read-write mode - no simultaneous readers allowed.

So you have two options to fix this:

1. Set the `replicas` in your ReplicationController to 1
2. Make the volume `readOnly: true`

   ```
   gcePersistentDisk:
     pdName: my-data-disk
     fsType: ext4
     readOnly: true
   ```

Comment: Ok, but if i want write on the disk and have more than one replicas ?

Comment: I try the second option , but the pods do not start.

Comment: @brokleen - can you do a `kubectl describe` to see what's happening with the pods?

Comment: @brokleen - also try with `replicas: 1` first and ensure things are fine. Then, start increasing it.

Comment: it works but i want create an apache server with 2 nodes and 2 pods and an ftp server. If i use your solution, i only have one pods and where i can found my files ?